# How duplicate each element of ArrayList n times?

Tags: java, java-8

I have to duplicate each element of my ArrayList n times. I tried to do this by:

```
List<String> elements = new ArrayList();
elements.add("1");
elements.add("2");
elements.add("3");
List<String> newList = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++){
        newList = Collections
                .nCopies(10, elements.get(i));
    }
```

but it repeats only last element of elements List 10 times

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment to me. Take a look at what you are doing inside the loop, and while debugging, keep an eye on the newList variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do reassign `newList =` each time, you're adding into the same one. You need to use `addAll`

- don't use raw generic , `new ArrayList() --> new ArrayList<>()`
- you can use foreach loop `for (String element : elements)`

```
List<String> elements = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3")
List<String> newList  = new ArrayList<>();
for (String element : elements) {
    newList.addAll(Collections.nCopies(10, element));
}

// [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

---

Using `Stream` it'll look like

```
List<String> newList = elements.stream()
                               .map(elt -> Collections.nCopies(10, elt))
                               .flatMap(List::stream)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Nice answer, informative and concise - just beat me to it... :)

Comment: You could specify an optimal initial capacity, `new ArrayList<>(elements.size() * 10)`. For the stream operation, there is no need to do two intermediate operations; `.flatMap(elt -> Collections.nCopies(10, elt).stream())` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

`newList` is reset every time you iterate through.

You have to append the items to newList each time.

```java
// Setup... Everything here is the same until later....
List<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
elements.add("1");
elements.add("2");
elements.add("3");
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

// Iterate (Still the same)
for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {

  // Here is the change:
  // "newList = Collections..." -> "newList.addAll(Collections...)"
  // This appends the new Collection to newList instead of resetting it
  newList.addAll(Collections.nCopies(10, elements.get(i)));
}
    
System.out.println("Started with: " + elements);
System.out.println("Ended with:   " + newList);

// Output
Started with: [1, 2, 3]
Ended with:   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```